# How to prevent a DIV from resizing itself when zooming out on a page?

Tags: css

I have a grid of six DIVs with background images. When zooming out, one DIV shrinks vertically proportionally to how zoomed out the browser is. This same DIV maintains proper proportions when zooming in.

I have tried setting min/max height and positioning. I found that changing the parent container to display: inline-block keeps everything proportional, but shrinks the perceived size and shifts everything over, which doesn't seem like an ideal solution.

Oddly, the identical elements on either side of it do not have this issue.

You can observe the phenomenon [here](https://fulhaus.com/collections/haus-in-a-box.).

```
<div id="element" class="collection-product">

  <div class="collection-box-2 card-shadow">
    <a href="/collections/haus-in-a-box/products/the-ful-kit-kitchen-utilities" class="grid_image_wrapper grid__image ">

      <img class="lazyload grid_image_absolute"
            src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0003/7204/7924/products/Copy_of_Li_Sylvie_Fulhaus_Room204_04_300x.jpg?v=1550866417"
            data-parent-fit="cover"
            data-src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0003/7204/7924/products/Copy_of_Li_Sylvie_Fulhaus_Room204_04_{width}x.jpg?v=1550866417"
            data-widths="[360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 2048]"
            data-aspectratio="1.0"
            data-sizes="auto"
            alt="the fül-kit (kitchen + utilities)" >
    </a>
    <div class="product-overlay">
      <a href="/collections/haus-in-a-box/products/the-ful-kit-kitchen-utilities" class="product-grid-card-wrapper"> </a>
      <div class="product-grid-card-link">
      <a href="/collections/haus-in-a-box/products/the-ful-kit-kitchen-utilities">
         <p class="h2 product-title">
          the fül-kit (kitchen + utilities)
        </p>


        <p class="h2 product-price"><span class="Bold-theme-hook-DO-NOT-DELETE bold_product_price" data-override-value-set="1" data-override-value="74700" style="display:none !important;"></span><span class=money>$747.00</span></p>

      </a>



      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="large--hide medium-down--show card-shadow mobile-square-title mobile-collection-margin-2"><a href="/collections/haus-in-a-box/products/the-ful-kit-kitchen-utilities" class="product-grid-card-link">
  <div class="mobile-price-container">
    <p class="h2 product-title">
      <a href="/collections/haus-in-a-box/products/the-ful-kit-kitchen-utilities">the fül-kit (kitchen +...</a>
    </p>


    <p class="h3 product-price">

      <span class="Bold-theme-hook-DO-NOT-DELETE bold_product_price_3" data-override-value-set="1" data-override-value="74700" style="display:none !important;"></span><span class=money>$747</span>

    </p>



  </div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try making the container div nested inside another div with `width` and `height` set to auto, then you could put the display of this new div set to `absolute`.

Comment: Zoom works differently across browsers. It's fool's errand to try to satisfy this requirement.